# Altium - convert blind via to through hole

Tags: altium

I want to convert blind vias to through hole (4 layer board) like shown below:

[image: th via]

How do I do this?

Comment: Delete the blind vias and add normal vias netted to the same places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple:

- Select the vias that you want to convert
- Right click on it - Properties
- Change the drill pair to Top Layer - Bottom Layer

You can also do the same operation from the PCB inspector

Comment: Thanks. This is the exact thing I was looking for.

Comment: Note that you can do a mass replacement by using 'find similar objects'

Comment: @PeterSmith - thanks for the tip. I have started using this tool very recently and being an eagle user, the options available with this tool feel overwhelming sometimes. :-)